# How to reinstall / reset lldb?

Tags: ios, macos, lldb

My LLDB seems like broken by a plugin. Its output seems a little bit weird like this:

```
Process 771 stopped
* thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x0000000100ac1000 cy-5Xn7dn.dylib`_dyld_start
cy-5Xn7dn.dylib`_dyld_start:
```

I don't know what `cy-5Xn7dn.dylib` is and I want to reinstall/reset my LLDB to fix this problem. Is there any possible way to reinstall or reset it?

*Update:*

This is otool information:

```
$ otool -l /usr/bin/lldb|grep " name"
         name /usr/lib/dyld (offset 12)
         name /usr/lib/libxcselect.dylib (offset 24)
         name /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (offset 24)
```

Comment: Remove the plugin?

Comment: @trojanfoe I have already removed the plugin by deleting all the content in `.lldbinit` file. The plugin seems not loaded after I did this. But the weird outputs are still there.

Comment: And you've restarted the shell?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, I also restarted my computer, but it didn't work.

Comment: You could try removing Xcode then I guess, using something like *AppCleaner*, and then reinstalling it.  It's crappy advise tho.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thank you for your advice, I'll try it.

Comment: @trojanfoe Also didn't work...

Comment: And you've done `find / -name cy-5Xn7dn.dylib` from the shell to check if this `.dylib` is real or not?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, it does not exist.

Comment: Can you provide output of `otool -l /usr/bin/lldb|grep " name"`?

Comment: @Kamil.S I have pasted it above.

Comment: @ZinLu your lldb looks legit. It seems something else is trying to load the `cy-5Xn7dn.dylib` either some rootkit or maybe some corporate administrative tool. You could also try `echo ${DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES}` in terminal.

Comment: @Kamil.S I tried `echo ${DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES}`, and the output is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is loading an alternative to the normal dynamic loader into the program you are running? I don’t think this is something lldb is doing, however. It is just relaying to you the dynamic library information that it got from the dynamic loader.

I’d first find that oddly named library and see if that tells you anything. You can use the lldb ‘image list <library_name>’ command to get the full path to the library. Is that in a place that maybe explains what it is?

It is possible to specify an alternate dynamic loader with the LC_DYLINKER command in the main binary. You might check the program you are debugging to see if it is doing that.

The DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES environment variable can also be used to force a program to load some other dylib. You should also make sure that isn’t being set. You can use ‘expr (char *) printenv(“DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES”)’ in lldb to check What it is in the app directly.

Comment: Note, it is not uncommon for tools that encrypt binaries to use a special purpose loader, to decrypt code on load. Maybe you are debugging a program that does that?

Comment: Yep, I am doing some iOS reverse engineering research. Thank you for your answer, I will try it later.

Comment: Here is `image list -o -f` result:
`[  1] 0x0000000104698000 /Library/Caches/cy-JXJcTY.dylib(0x0000000104698000)`
but I can't find the dylib under `/Library/Caches` directory.